# Proof about periodic points

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

I have to prove that between two consecutive points of an orbit of period $n>1$, exists a periodic point of period less than $n$.

My idea : If $a$ and $b$, $a<b$ are two consecutive points of the orbit $O(x,f)$, then the number of elements of $O(x,f)$ that are to the left of $a$ is less by one unit than the number of elements in $O(x, f)$ that are to the left of $b$

Comment: Please specify  exactly what you are talking about here.  Iteration of a continuous function on an interval?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, iteration of a continuous fuction on an interval

Comment: So what sets your problem apart from the general setting of Sharkovsky theory is that there are two consecutive points of the orbit, say $a<b=f(a)$ and inside $[a,b]$ there are no other points of the orbit. Or did I read too much into the task description?